# Fast combine multidimensional array with custom key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Base on this data :

```
Array
(
    [from] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-08-23 15:33:14
                    [1] => 2015-08-23 15:38:01
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-08-23 09:39:23
                    [1] => 2015-08-23 15:44:23
                )

        )

    [to] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-08-23 15:38:01
                    [1] => 2015-08-23 15:42:22
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-08-23 15:44:23
                    [1] => 2015-08-23 18:15:38
                )
        )

)
```

I need result like this : array[from][0][0] combine with array[to][0][0] as array[0][0]

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [from] => 2015-08-23 15:33:14
                [to] => 2015-08-23 15:38:01
            )
        ...
    )
...
```

I try with many loop (it's so ugly) and i doubt the performance is bad when a lot of data

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do the trick.

```
$count1 = count($data);
$result = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $count1; $i++) {
    $count2 = count($data['from'][$i]);
    for($j = 0; $j < $count2; $j++) {
        $result[$i][$j] = array(
            "from" => $data['from'][$i][$j],
            "to" => $data['to'][$i][$j]
        );

    }
}
```